# Get exact date by providing week number of month and day?

Tags: php, date

Is there any php function where i can get exact date, by providing week number of the month and day as,

```
function required_date($week_num, $day) {
// should return 20th of September, if i pass (3, 'Friday')
}
```

I am getting week number of the month as

```
ceil(substr(date('Y-m-d'), -2) / 7);
```

and day as,

```
date('l');
```

Any help, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function required_date($week_num, $day) {
  $week_of_year = sprintf('%02d', date('W', strtotime(date('Y-m-01'))) + $week_num);
  $day_of_week  = date('N', strtotime($day));
  $timestamp    = strtotime(date('Y') . '-W' . $week_of_year . '-' . $day_of_week);

  return $timestamp;
}


$timestamp = required_date(3, 'friday');
echo date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('W' . $week_num . ' ' . $day));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
function required_date($week_num, $day) 
{
    return date('Y-m-') . substr('0' . (($week_num - 1) * 7 + date('N', strtotime($day))) + 1, -2);
}

var_dump(required_date(3, 'Friday'));
var_dump(required_date(4, 'Friday'));
```

Comment: @IrfanAhmed: what should `required_date(1, 'Sunday')` return?